# How can you spawn ender dragon after you kill it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've killed the Ender Dragon, and I'd like to fight it again.

How can you respawn the Ender dragon after you kill it?

Answer (score 1):

Place four ender crystals on the corners of the second end portal, the one that fills in after you kill the Ender Dragon.

Comment: Not the corners, the sides.

Comment: That's not actually nessecary, as long as four ender crystals are on the bedrock edge.